# Loops and breaks

Tags: javascript

SO I have this assignment.

/*  CONVERT: Sandwich code
Using a FOR loop and a single IF statement within the loop, see which radio button they checked. When you find it, set g_sSandwich to the sandwich name and break out of the loop using the break command. If nothing is selected, set divErrors to "Select a sandwich", and exit the function. But how do you know if nothing was selected?  Use a boolean variable in the If statement, then check its value after you get out of the loop.Remember: Your code should be flexible enough so that if the number of sandwiches change, your code can still work.
Afterall, that's one of the reasons we're using a loop.
        Do NOT call the GetSandwichName() function.  Incorporate its code here, and remove it.
    */

**this is what I have so far:** 
What I don't understand is how am I suppose to use a boolean variable to check if it is false? I don't understand.

```
var i = 0;

for (i = g_radSandwich.length -1; i++ ) {
    if (g_radSandwich[i].checked === true) {
        g_sSandwich = g_radSandwich[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You for loop is not correct.

```
var isChecked = false;
for (var i = 0; i < g_radSandwich.length; i++ ) {
    if (g_radSandwich[i].checked === true) {
        isChecked = true;
        g_sSandwich = g_radSandwich[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
if (isChecked) {
   // do something
```

Beyond that, you should set a global variable as false, and then if one of the `if` statements is true you switch the global variable to true. Then afterwards you know whether something has changed.

Comment: TBH there is way more the assignment than that. Can you please show me an example?

Comment: See all that makes way more sense, but my teacher not once ever explained doing it like that. Would you mind looking over the whole assignment (Full javascript / HTMl). I am not asking you to do my assignment, I just don't thik my instructors instructions make the most sense...

Comment: Yea, the question is answered but that doesn't solve my problem at all. Thanks though I guess

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define your for loop correctly

```
for (conter initialization; condition to continue; counter modifier)
```

It is not strictly necessary to set all three, but it is desired.

For the `if` statment, you need to set boolean condition, so
Instead of

```
if (g_radSandwich[i].checked === true) // correct, but redundant
```

replace to

```
if (g_radSandwich[i].checked)
```

If you need to check reverse of condition, you need to put `!` symbol

```
if (!g_radSandwich[i].checked) // is radSandwitch[i].checked is false
```

Comment: Could you check your twitter